# Fire onChange event of one radio input when another radio input with the same name changes

Tags: reactjs

I have a radio input component which listens to onChange event. I also have a wrapper element that listens to onClick event. Both the event handlers set the same state. I would want the onChange event of another radio input to dispatch when some other radio input with the same name is changed.

[Here's my problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/rlojp2rw9q)

Answer (score 0):

I am also new in react, but I think you should also handle onclick event at app level when you call up your element.

```
<RadioButton label="label1" name="sameName" onClick={*dosomething*} />
```

set props in the component  clicked and restore the props in the other one....

I'm also curious for the solution

Answer (score 0):

Edit (following our conversation in the comments):
The onchange event of the other radio buttons should not be fired.
Why? because although these are multiple radio buttons, they still represent a single input (a single answer to a single question).
Thus, when one of the options is checked, only one value changes, so only one onchange event should be fired.

For example, if we select a fruit using a radio input:

```
const RadioInput = ({ name, value, label }) => (
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name={ name } value={ value }/>
    <label>{ label }</label>
  </div>
);

const RadioGroup = ({ name = 'fruit' }) => (
  <div>
    <RadioInput name={ name } value="mango" label="Mango"/>
    <RadioInput name={ name } value="banana" label="Banana"/>
    <RadioInput name={ name } value="melon" label="Melon"/>
  </div>
);
```

Then when we check one of the options, we are answering a single question: which fruit do we want?

That's why it is represented by a single onchange event.

Comment: But isn't allowing user to select one option amongst a few achievable with inputs with same name, radio input that is. Can you tell why you don't recommend it ? About the question itself, checking/unchecking a radio input fires onchange event on itself, but with radio inputs with same name the other radio input in the group also changes its state, no ? But the onchange event on that input does not fire. I wanted to thus fire onchange event of the other radio input.

Comment: I've misunderstood your question, I will edit my response and remove the part about inputs with the same name and multiple selection, and add my answer there.